# Python script and equivalent command do not run the same

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I would like to use youtubedl to download the audio from a YouTube video into an mp3 file. I came up with the following command to do so:

`youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF8DGbfOFig&ab_channel=derang`

When I run the above command through my command line, it seems that I successfully manage to download the file in mp3 format:

```
[youtube] SF8DGbfOFig: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k]-SF8DGbfOFig.webm
[download] 100% of 5.57MiB in 00:03
[ffmpeg] Destination: Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k]-SF8DGbfOFig.mp3
Deleting original file Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k]-SF8DGbfOFig.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

I then tried to convert the above command to an equivalent python script as follows:

```
import youtube_dl
links = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF8DGbfOFig&ab_channel=derang"]
ydl_args = {
        'audioformat': 'mp3',
        'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'extractaudio': True
    }
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_args) as ydl:
    results = ydl.download(links)
```

However, this does not succeed in generating an mp3 file of the audio. These are the logs I am getting:

```
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k].f135.mp4
[download] 100% of 4.42MiB in 00:02
[download] Destination: Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k].f251.webm
[download] 100% of 5.57MiB in 00:03
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k].mkv"
Deleting original file Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k].f135.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k].f251.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Aren't my command and python script equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

1. First List available extentions that you want to get, like

   youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF8DGbfOFig

where **-F (UPPER)** list all items, some like

[image: with -F list all options to download]

2. Download audio only, in the extention that you want, in the example I choose the "140", with the **-f (in lowercase)** option like that:

[image: choice an option to download item]

```
youtube-dl -f 140 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF8DGbfOFig
```

Now you have an m4a file, in this example will be *"Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k]-SF8DGbfOFig.m4a"*

to continue in this example, I change the original file name to "original.m4a" to easy explain

`mv "Total Science & S.P.Y - Piano Funk (Ft. Riya & DāM FunK) [320k]-SF8DGbfOFig.m4a" original.m4a`

---

3. You have to use ffmpeg to encode/decode this file to mp3 (ffmpeg option is an easy option and Human Anti-sickness)

An easy code can be

```
ffmpeg -i "original.m4a" audio.mp3
```

and you can use options like

- -ac for channels, 2 for stereo, 1 for mono.
- -ar for audio rate, 48000, 44100, etc.
- -b:a for quality (bitrate) 320k, 256k, 128k, 96k, etc.
- -dn for remove all data but not metadata, it remove  like titles, etc,
- -map_metadata -1 for remove all metadata

example `ffmpeg -i "original.m4a" -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 320k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -dn -map_metadata -1 audio_edit.mp3`

King regards